# what is the best way to locally store 2048 * 2048 webgl texture

Tags: local-storage, textures, webgl

I would like to locally store a webgl texture of size 2048*2048. 
Is it possible to store it in the browser's local storage as an uint8array? or perhaps there is a better way? (e.g., a screen shot taken during the game..)

Thanks

Comment: How many of those files do you have? `localstorage` and `sessionstorage` might provide what you need for a few files, but if you need more you might be better using some web-based database to store it as a `BLOB`.

Comment: What do you mean by store? Like a cookie if the user comes back?
You can store [BLOBs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) in [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB). Blobs can contain Uint8Arrays. IndexedDB is non-trivial to use so you might want to [consider using a library](http://dexie.org/). That gets stored in the user's browser. Otherwise you'd normally send the screenshot to server so the user can log in from any computer and see their screenshot. Also the canvas has a `toBlob` function to make a screenshot